# Let $G$ be a finite simple group and let $H\subset G$ be a abelian subgroup of index $|G:H|=p$. Prove that $H = \{e\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a finite simple group and let $H\subset G$ be a abelian subgroup of index $|G:H|=p$ for $p$ some prime.
Prove that $H = \{e\}$.

I don't know how to start...
Plz someone help me.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime number?

Comment: yes, $p$ is prime number

Comment: Hint : show that $H$ such that $|G:H|=p$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That is not correct in that generality.

Comment: @Silement To add a bit of specificity to Jose Carlos Santos's suggestion, please see the section about adding context. It is very difficult for us to help you if you don't tell us what your thoughts and background are, since without that information, all we can do is post the explanation that we think is most clear to us, which may or may not be helpful to you.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sorry, I thought (I don't know why) that $p$ was the smallest prime number dividing the order of $G$... In this case, I think that $H$ is normal. In general, you are right, it is not the case. Thanks you for the correction !

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can offer two proofs of this statement.  The first is short, but makes use of a difficult theorem (due to [Herstein](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2033148); an alternative proof [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/112198)):

> Theorem: A finite group with an abelian maximal subgroup is solvable.

The proof is not elementary, as it involves the Frobenius complement.  But it makes short work of the present question:

In our case, $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ because $|G:H|$ is prime; thus $G$ is solvable.  However, the only simple groups which are solvable are the prime-order cyclic groups.  Hence $G\cong C_p$ and $H$ is trivial.

---

By making earlier use of the hypothesis that $G$ is simple and borrowing an idea from Herstein, I have cobbled together an elementary proof:

If $G$ is abelian, then it must be prime-order cyclic and we are done.  So we will assume that $G$ is a nonabelian simple group and show that this results in a contradiction.

$H$ is not trivial, for then $G$ would be of prime order and thus abelian.  Thus $H$ is not normal.  Let $K$ be a conjugate of $H$.  Since $K\cong H$, $K$ is also abelian.

Claim: $H\cap K$ is trivial.

If $h \in H\cap K$, then the centralizer of $h$ contains $H$ (since $H$ is abelian) and $K$ (likewise).  Since $H$ is maximal and the centralizer of $h$ is larger, it must be all of $G$.  But $G$ is nonabelian simple, so its center is trivial.  Hence $h = 1$.

Let $n = |G|$, so $|H| = |K| = n/p$. Then $|HK|=\dfrac{|H|\,|K|}{|H\cap K|} = n^2/p^2$.  $HK$ is a subset of $G$, so $n^2/p^2 \le n$; thus $n \le p^2$.  It cannot be the case that $n=p^2$, since all groups of order $p^2$ are abelian.  Hence $n \lt p^2$ and $n/p \lt p$.  The number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ is a divisor of $n/p$ and is congruent to $1\pmod p$, so it must be $1$.  Thus the Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal, which contradicts the simplicity of $G$.

---

I suspect that there is a simpler elementary proof, so I hope that this awkward approach will provoke someone into embarrassing me by posting it.

Comment: Shouldn't the end of your proof be "hence the $p$-Sylow is normal; therefore it is $G$, which is absurd as nonabelian $p$-groups aren't simple" ? Otherwise where did you remove the possibility that $G$ be a $p$-group ?

Comment: @Max The group is already of order less than $p^2$ and not cyclic of order $p$, so it cannot be a $p$-group.

Comment: @jgon : oh right, my bad !